# Test what face of a cuboid is in contact with the floor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am currently working on a game where I will have to **move a cuboid** using the arrow keys, bearing in mind the constraints of a chessboard.

The object will only be able to move step by step, meaning:

- If it is up and you press any key: it will fall in that direction and
  put itself on its side.
- If it is on its side: it will move 1 step in
  that direction.

I have a script that does just that... for a cube. However, I can't make it work with a cuboid.

I am thinking I should check which face is actually in contact with the floor and then do a different move according to the result.

- If one of the 2 square faces in in contact with the floor, I should
  do just what my script currently does.
- If one of the 4 rectangular
  faces is in contact with the floor, I should adapt my script to move
  it the same way.

Does that seem like a good solution? If so, can you help me figure out the condition I have to write to check what face is currently in contact with the floor?

**My UnityScript** (which I intend to convert to C#)

```
var rotator : Transform;
var speed = 1.0;
var halfSize = 0.5;
private var rotating = false;

function RotateCube(refPoint : Vector3, rotationAxis : Vector3) {
    rotator.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    rotator.position = transform.position -Vector3.up*halfSize + refPoint;
    transform.parent = rotator;
    var angle : float = 0;

    while(angle < 90.0) {
        angle += Time.deltaTime*90.0*speed;
        rotator.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Mathf.Min(angle,90.0),rotationAxis);
        yield;
    }

    transform.parent = null;
    rotating = false;
}

function Start() {
    rotator = (new GameObject("Rotator")).transform;
}

function Update () {
    if (!rotating) {
        if (Input.GetKey("right")) {
            rotating = true;
            RotateCube(Vector3.right*halfSize,-Vector3.forward);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("left")) {
            rotating = true;
            RotateCube(-Vector3.right*halfSize,Vector3.forward);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("up")) {
            rotating = true;
            RotateCube(Vector3.forward*halfSize,Vector3.right);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("down")) {
            rotating = true;
            RotateCube(-Vector3.forward*halfSize,-Vector3.right);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
function OnCollisionEnter(Collision : collision)
```

to detect any collisions. If you want to detect collisions in every frame the use

```
function OnCollisionStay(Collision : collision)
```

Check out their description [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) and [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html).

Then use `collision.contacts` to detect the points of contact ([description](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html)).

Here is an example:

```
function OnCollisionStay(collision : Collision) {
    for (var contact : ContactPoint in collision.contacts) {
        print(contact.thisCollider.name + " hit " + contact.otherCollider.name);
        // Visualize the contact point
        Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
    }
}
```